# Why can't I start tablet form factor Android devices in the emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

Last time I used the emulator for tablet sized devices was probably a month or 2 ago and it was fine then.  However, now I can't launch tablets.  The tablet window pops up, but stays completely blank.  No boot screen or anything.  I've been Googling around and have rebooted multiple times, but no luck.  No error messages.  Phone sized devices work just fine (on multiple API levels).  Anyone else have this problem and solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, in the older version of AVD, tablet devices refuse to start if set to x86.  Switching to arm allows them to start.

Of some related note, on the very latest Android Studio, no devices of type x86 will start for me, but the same devices in arm work fine.  Wondering if perhaps Google has made some sort of emulation change?